# Global Navigation menu in diiferrent wordpress setups

Tags: theme-development, menus, child-theme

I have 2 different wordpress sites but I have deployed it like
**www.xyz.com and www.xyz.com/news** Now I am trying to get main menu from www.xyz.com and it should work with www.xyz.com/news

**main purpose of this functionality if I am changing any menu link or adding new page so it should automatically add to the other website.**

Comment: please let me know why my question got -1

Answer (score 0):

The way you've 'deployed' this is very unconventional. You should have just set your post page to be the 'News' page.

However, to answer your question. In appearance > menus > select menu you would like to edit, you can use something known as custom links, in which you can then add the same title as your www.xyz.com site, with the link from www.xyz.com over on your www.xyz.com/news site.

[image]